# Where could the water leaking from in my Dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

It will only leak during the first 2 minutes of the cycle and than cleans the dishes fine.
The leaking is from somewhere at the bottom of the case in the center where the arm and filters are housed,
not from any hose underneath the case.

Whirpool WDTA50SAHZ0

Wish I could upload a video.

Comment: What  cycle is it leaking on? Fill,Wash,Rinse, Drain?

Comment: You can post a link to a video hosted elsewhere. You can also post pictures of the leak - draw some arrows on the pic if it's not 100% clear from the pic where the leak is originating.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a number of things (any part that carries water could leak...) and is therefore unanswerable as asked.

However, prior to voting to close this question I will say that the main unit that is located centrally in the bottom of the tub and contains the motor, pump(s), and main spray arm usually has a large diameter ring gasket that is the primary seal between the water in the tub and the floor beneath the unit.